# JQuery function produces desired result on Page_Load but not on Button_Click event -- how to make the JQuery work On Demand?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

The following JQuery function generates tooltips for a gridview on the same page on the Page Load event, and this all works fine -- I get the tooltips when I hover over (column1). But if I try to run the same JQuery from a button click -- after the page has loaded -- the tooltips do not get generated.

The JQuery reads a list from an html table that gets generated on Page Load (from code behind that writes the data to html) and puts this (html) data into an object array which gets passed to a webmethod in a webservice, and then I have my tooltips -- on the Page Load event.  But if I (uncomment out the button click part) add a button click to the JQuery -- the code is executed, and the object array ***DOES*** get sent to the webmethod in the webservice, but no tooltips are generated.

Is there a way I can emulate the Page Load event on the button click here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //--btn1 click is commented out here -- this functions works OK on Page Load
$(function () {
    //$("[id*=btn1]").click(function () {
        var tbl = $('#tstTbl tr:has(td)').map(function (i, v) {
            var $td = $('td', this);
            return {
                id: ++i,
                firstN: $td.eq(0).text(),
                lastN: $td.eq(1).text(),
            }
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Service1.asmx/ttArr",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ttC:" + JSON.stringify(tbl) + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('[id*=GridViewA] tr').each(function (n) {
                    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").each(function () {
                        var titel = typeof (data.d[n - 1]) === 'undefined' ? "" : data.d[n - 1].firstN + "<br />" + data.d[n - 1].lastN;
                        $(this).tooltip({ title: $(this).addClass("colr-tooltip"), title: titel, html: true, placement: "bottom" });
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            }
        });
    //});
});

</script>
```

Here's the markup for the gridview, btn1, ...

```
........
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" Text="testBtn" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridViewA_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itm0" HeaderText="itm0A" />                
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itm1" HeaderText="itm1B" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itm2" HeaderText="itm2C" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itm3" HeaderText="itm3D" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itm4" HeaderText="itm4E" />  
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table id="tstTbl" >
            <tbody id="tstBody" runat="server"> the <tr>s and <td>s created from code behind </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

incase anyone cares, here's the webmethod and the object class

```
    ......
    [WebMethod]
    public List<stuffC> ttArr(List<stuffC> ttC)
    {
        return ttC;
    }    
}

public class stuffC
{
    public string firstN { get; set; }
    public string lastN { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `<asp:Button runat="server"...` is going to do a postback, so it's likely kicking off your jQuery function and then reloading the page entirely.  Why are you using `asp:Button` if the functionality is client side?  Just use `<input type="button"...`

Comment: Right on!  That works.  I just need this to work in the actual app where I use an asp button that does stuff then I need to update the tooltips each time this one asp button gets click.  Is there a way to make it also click the <input type="button"   ?